# How to reuse a nested listview's delegate?

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, qml

I have a nested listview structure where the delegate listview will contain another listview.  I would like the nested listview's delegate to refer to itself because the nested listview will contain the same type of item as itself, but this doesn't appear to work.

```
Component {
    id: subSequenceComponent

    ItemDelegate {
        id: subSequenceItemDelegate
        property var id: edit.id
        ColumnLayout {

            Text{
                text: edit.name
            }

            ListView {
                width: 180; height: 200

                model: items.subModelFromId(subSequenceItemDelegate.id)
                delegate: subSequenceComponent
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This works:

```
Component {
id: subSequenceComponent

ItemDelegate {
    id: subSequenceItemDelegate
    property var id: edit.id
    ColumnLayout {

        Text{
            text: edit.name
        }

        ListView {
            width: 180; height: 200

            model: items.subModelFromId(subSequenceItemDelegate.id)
            delegate: Text{
            text: edit.name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to reuse the same delegate you are a part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be connected to this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56292). Basically, QML has some checks that are supposed to prevent accidental infinite recursions, but they are not particularly well implemented, and trigger false positives even for scenario where nesting is intended and there is no danger of infinite recursion.

If that is the case, then you can trick that check by using an additional `Loader` that will load the component from a string, which will not catch the nesting recursion.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Initially, I found that the loader was not working because the qml file that contained the ItemDegate was encapsulated in a Component.  I needed to ensure that the QML file only contained an ItemDelegate and I loaded the delegate like this:   delegate: Component { Loader { source: "SubSequenceItemDelegate.qml"} }